# Converting JSON to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

I set up a test DreamFactory server and I am trying to transform the results from JSON to a DataTable so I can display a GridView. I've tried several things with  no success, this is my current code:

```
 var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic d = JObject.Parse(result);
            }

            object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result); 

            var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(result); <--ERROR
            return table;
```

I've tried several methods but I am getting the following error most of the time:

**Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.**

It can deserialize fine as the object shows me the full deserialized JSON with no problems. Anything I can do?

EDIT: JSON Structure

```
{"record":[{"StatusID":1, "Identifier":"DQRJO1Q0IQRS",
 "Status":"WaitList",
"StatusDate":"2014-11-15",
"WorkedBy":"None",
"ContactedOn":"2014-11-15T14:21:55.623",
"Email":"email}]}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? You mixed all your trials in one code? BTW: `I've tried several methods but I am getting the following error most of the time` is not a question. When? With which code?

Comment: Argh sorry let me clean that up (I commented them but still)

Comment: what is the structure of the JSON?

Comment: And the content of `result` ?

Comment: Posted the JSON format

Comment: `DataTable table = (DataTable) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, (typeof(DataTable)));`

Comment: The JSON I posted is also the values in the result variable. I verified this with several breakpoints.

Comment: Avijit I got the same error: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: I have seen that there is no " mark `"Email":"email}]}`

Comment: Sorry deleted it when sanitizing the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json isn't a  DataTable. All you need is to deserialize to

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

---

```
public class Record
{
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusDate { get; set; }
    public string WorkedBy { get; set; }
    public string ContactedOn { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Record> Record { get; set; }
}
```

*See [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) for further json to csharp convertions*

Comment: Ok that seemed to work very well, thanks a lot. I verified the list and the data was deserialized correctly. If you don't mind, how can I turn "root" into a DataTable?

Comment: @LordRelix Create a data table and fill the values using root object. This isn't related with json deserialization.

Comment: You are right. Still got it working after some tinkering. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need To convert it To a datatable. It should work when converting To a strongly typed object. Quite sure it won't work with dynamic although. 
and bind it from the result object, the datasource should be an Array.